# ESP32 not seen by a network analyzer application in server mode

Tags: esp32

I have used the **scan wifi** and **blink** examples provided by Espressif,
they are both working on the ESP32 using arduino ide.

However, I can not see my ESP( the SSID and signal strength) in the list of detected wifi when searching for it using a network analyzer app  ( Net analyzer on android)

This was solved when I used the ESP as Access point.
In Client mode the ESP is using the WIFI capability. But why it can not be seen by others?

why is the ESP32 Lolin getting hot only when it is in AP mode?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "see" it? And what NA app? Are you assuming it should be an AP by default? Have you programmed it to be an AP and broadcast an SSID?

Comment: Can't a client be seen by all? So the problem is that I need to make it as an AP? My point is to use the ESP as client on assets and make the access point know the position using its signal strength.

Comment: Only access points can be seen by stations. When connected you use other protocols (mDNS) to advertise services.

Answer (score 1):

> In Client mode the ESP is using the WIFI capability. But why it can
>   not be seen by others?

The app is looking for access points. (if it is looking for SSID) And if you do not have the ESP set as an access point it will not be seen.

> why is the ESP32 Lolin getting hot only when it is in AP mode?

Because the radio is on all the time. It has to be available for a connection. When it is not an access point, the ESP goes into a sleep mode when it does not have any need to communicate.